# Issue with using TokensRegexNERAnnotator

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I would like to know how to use 'TokensRegexNERAnnotator' in java.
I have seen in documentation that it can be used as same as 'RegexNER' so I created a file with list of patterns and classes delimited with tab and I added a property called 'tokensregexner' to property file and used as below but it is showing an error message that 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No annotator named tokensregexner'.

```
properties.put("annotators",
    "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, tokensregexner");
properties.put("tokensregexner.mapping",
    "com/test/ner/resources/entities.txt");
coreNLP = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);
```

Can someone please share some sample code on how to use this 'TokensRegexNERAnnotator' through Java

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue you are facing is that there is no property named tokensregexner.  There is a property named regexner and I think that is what you are after.  So the code would look like:

```
properties.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, regexner");
properties.put("regexner.mapping", "com/test/ner/resources/entities.txt");
coreNLP = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties);
```